# How to remove duplicate columns from a JOIN in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I find that when using a JOIN in SQLITE, I get a double of the column on which I joined the 2 tables. I need a way so that when I JOIN 2 TABLES, I can delete the duplicate column.

I want for there to be only one of the 2 circled rows:

[image: image of the duplicate columns]

This is the code that I am using to join the:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stops 
JOIN stop_times ON stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
```

Comment: What is the logic behind which two rows to keep?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It just that I am joining the 2 tables on those variables so having 2 of them becomes redundant. I just chose one of them using ```stops.stop_id``` to make sure that it knows which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `SELECT *` with the list of columns and use table aliases in order to indicate the table that contains the column.

You didn't post the structure of the tables, so I can't give you a complete solution, but maybe the below SQL is enough in order for you to complete by yourself.

```sql
SELECT s.stop_id
      ,s.stop_code
      ,t.arrival_time
      ,t.departure_time
  FROM stops s
  JOIN stop_times t
    ON s.stop_id = t.stop_id
```

Comment: Yes, I just had a eureka moment where I understood this. Thanks for the help tho.